# Unable to trigger change event of a dropdown element in document ready

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In `$(document).ready()`, I am setting a particular dropdown's first element to be selected. I also need to trigger the change function on the dropdown as if the option were manually selected. If the change is triggered, the `showTestsByPanel` function is called and shows appropriate data associated with the selected dropdown option.

I am doing the following, but it doesn't help trigger the change function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lbpanel option:first-child").attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#lbpanel').trigger('change'); // <-- this is not triggering the change

    $('#lbpanel').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var parentId = $("#lbpanel").find("option:selected").val();
        $("#selectedTests tr").each(function () {
            showTestsByPanel(parentId, $(this));
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried `$('#lbpanel').change()` instead, but that did not work as well.

If it helps:

- this whole thing is inside a modal dialog.
- this is actually a listbox where `allowmultiple` is set to false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the change event after the trigger handlers are registered, when the event is triggered it will invoke only those handlers which are already registered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lbpanel option:first-child").attr('selected', 'selected');

    $('#lbpanel').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var parentId = $("#lbpanel").find("option:selected").val();
        $("#selectedTests tr").each(function () {
            showTestsByPanel(parentId, $(this));
        });
    }).trigger('change'); // need to trigger the event after the handler is added
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to trigger `change` event before handler creation. That's why no effect.

So call the `change()` after registering `change` event handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lbpanel option:first-child").attr('selected', true);
    $('#lbpanel').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var parentId = $("#lbpanel").find("option:selected").val();
        $("#selectedTests tr").each(function () {
            showTestsByPanel(parentId, $(this));
        });
    }).change(); //added change here
});
```